# How can you update claims in OWIN CookieAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, owin

In an ASP.NET application using the OWIN pipeline, I am attempting to use cookie authentication & override CookieAuthenticationProvider.ValidateIdentity and do something similar to:

```cs
public override Task ValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context) {
    Claim simpleClaim = context.Identity.FindFirst("SIMPLECOUNT");
    if (simpleClaim != null) {
        Trace.WriteLine($"SIMPLECOUNT: {simpleClaim.Value}");
        if (context.Identity.TryRemoveClaim(simpleClaim)) {
            var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Identity);
            int newcount = 1 + int.Parse(simpleClaim.Value);
            newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("SIMPLECOUNT", newcount.ToString()));
            context.ReplaceIdentity(newIdentity);
        }               
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

In reality I am updating other claims, and only doing this occasionally. But this highlights the main confusion. I can call context.RejectIdentity() or I can call context.ReplaceIdentity(). Presumably if I call the "reject", the old ClaimsIdentity would be a goner. So if instead I repeatedly *replace* a ClaimsIdentity after wiping the old claim value, and adding back the claim with an incremented value, I'd expect *never to see* the old value again.

But that is not the case at all. The same value keeps coming back. By playing with cookie timeout settings I can see that an incremented claim value eventually shows up once the cookie has been replaced due sliding expiration. Where is the new value even being "queued" that it would eventually update?

As for the recurring *old value*, is this the cookie from the browser reasserting itself? I don't want to have to sign the user out to update the claims -- in fact I am seriously only using claims as storage because I don't know what else I can use in this context (as opposed to controller methods). Is there a better approach? Ultimately what I am trying to do is synchronize cookie expirations with an updated API token written to the *new* cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably a bit late but I found out that if you sign the user in again the old claims are replaced with the new ones. So your case would look like this.

```
public override Task ValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context) {
    Claim simpleClaim = context.Identity.FindFirst("SIMPLECOUNT");
    if (simpleClaim != null) {
        Trace.WriteLine($"SIMPLECOUNT: {simpleClaim.Value}");
        if (context.Identity.TryRemoveClaim(simpleClaim)) {
            var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Identity);
            int newcount = 1 + int.Parse(simpleClaim.Value);
            newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("SIMPLECOUNT", newcount.ToString()));

            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(newIdentity);
        }               
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```